# Copying the first commit from a git branch to an empty branch

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a `master` branch, in which I want to create an `empty` branch that contains the first commit of the `master` branch, **with the same hash** (the last point is very important). I tried cherry-picking, but this doesn't give a commit with the same hash:

```
$ git log  # we are on master
commit bfe76c82dace725e84e09dfa472b4ccef91495c6
Author: Name <email>
Date:   Wed Apr 10 15:40:45 2013 +0200

    Made some changes to README

commit 8b4c9dbcb4c5c0f966780f8b2f7ba356e3480fca
Author: Name <email>
Date:   Wed Apr 10 15:39:35 2013 +0200

    Added README

$ git checkout --orphan empty
Switched to a new branch 'empty'

$ git rm --cached *
rm 'README.rst'

$ git clean -fxd
Removing README.rst

$ git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

$ git cherry-pick 8b4c9dbcb4c5c0f966780f8b2f7ba356e3480fca
[empty (root-commit) 1556211] Added README
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README.rst

$ git log
commit 1556211343e404861ba9f7ec627b6d6f216217e0
Author: Name <email>
Date:   Wed Apr 10 15:39:35 2013 +0200

    Added README
```

As you can see, the hash of the first commit is different. What is the easiest way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On master,

```
git branch empty 8b4c9dbcb4c5c0f966780f8b2f7ba356e3480fca
```

or

```
git checkout -b empty 8b4c9dbcb4c5c0f966780f8b2f7ba356e3480fca
```